# controls property of video tag

Tags: html

Your browser does not support the video tag.

When the mouse pointer is on the div area which contains the video, the video is shaking. But when the controls in the video tag is removed , no shaking. Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video id="movie" width="320" height="320" preload controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="pr6.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
  <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param ... />
  </object>
</video>
```

This example is taken from the book HTML5 Up and Running. You list each supported video encoding separately within a single  tag. The browser will try each one, starting with the first. This example shows three encodings. You will need do the actual video encoding yourself. To support multiple browsers, you'll need multiple encodings.

The final entry is a fallback for browsers that don't support the new HTML5 video tag. In the example, I used flash, but you can use whatever old-school format you prefer.

Comment: The poster did not show their code which makes the question off topic. You have no way of knowing if that is his issue at all or if this solves it.

Comment: Note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. Same for `<param>` but that has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for over 20 years.